# Sort strings/words alphabetically separated by comma within a column in SQL (entire column)

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say that I have a table the following data:
(there are a 1000+ more rows like this)

```
Bird  
----------------------------
Sparrow, Eagle, Crow
Woodpecker, Sparrow
Crow, Eagle                     
etc. etc.
```

I want the final column to be sorted out alphabetically. Something like this:

```
Bird  
--------------------
Crow, Eagle, Sparrow
Sparrow, Woodpecker   
Crow, Eagle                    
etc. etc.
```

Need to know a SQL query that can do that. Possibly SQL Developer.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble...

Comment: SQL-Server/Developer 
Wanted to know the SQL query that can possibly help me sort them .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server sort comma separated string in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769913/sql-server-sort-comma-separated-string-in-one-column)

Comment: why have you got multiple values in a single row? This is not a good data structure, as already mentioned.

Comment: "SQL-Server/Developer"...are you sure? AFAIK the product known as "SQL Developer" is used to connect to Oracle databases, not SQL Server. Unless there is another product of the same name? Or it has capabilities I was unaware of.

Comment: I have a data set that comes in that format. Is there a possible way that I can write an SQL query that can arrange them alphabetically.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've already looked at the post. It's similar to that, but it's not for an entire column for a table.I need that for the entire column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an Oracle solution using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to break the problem down.  Not sure if this will help, but maybe it will give you an idea or a starting point that you can apply to your environment.

```
SQL> -- Set up original data set
SQL> with bird_tbl(id, unsorted_list) as (
     select 1, 'Sparrow, Eagle, Crow' from dual union all
     select 2, 'Woodpecker, Sparrow' from dual union all
     select 3, 'Crow, Eagle' from dual
   ),
   -- Split the list into a row for each element
   split_tbl(id, bird) as (
     select id, regexp_substr(unsorted_list, '(.*?)(, |$)', 1, level, null, 1)
     from bird_tbl
     connect by level <= regexp_count(unsorted_list, ', ')+1
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
   )
   -- select * from split_tbl;
   -- Rebuild the sorted row
   select id, listagg(bird, ', ')
     within group (order by bird) sorted_list
     from split_tbl
     group by id;

        ID SORTED_LIST
---------- --------------------
         1 Crow, Eagle, Sparrow
         2 Sparrow, Woodpecker
         3 Crow, Eagle
```

EDIT: Here's how to apply to your situation.  Just replace `<your_primary_key>` with the primary key column name, `<your_column_name>` with the name of the column that contains the unsorted list and `<your_table_name>` with the name of the table.

```
with split_tbl(<your_primary_key>, <your_column_name>) as (
     select <your_primary_key>, regexp_substr(<your_column_name>, '(.*?)(, |$)', 1, level, null, 1)
     from <your_table_name>
     connect by level <= regexp_count(<your_column_name>, ', ')+1
       and prior <your_primary_key> = <your_primary_key>
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
   )
   -- select * from split_tbl;
   -- Rebuild the sorted row
   select <your_primary_key>, listagg(<your_column_name>, ', ')
     within group (order by <your_column_name>) sorted_list
     from split_tbl
     group by <your_primary_key>;
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but my main concern is that I have 1000+ rows, how could I possibly have the first part look directly at the column and perform the steps.

Comment: bird_tbl just sets up test data for this example.  It really starts at split_tbl, where you would point to your column instead of "unsorted_list", and your table instead of "bird_tbl".

Comment: should I replace 'unsorted-list' with 'bird', in order for it to work? I don't have an id column either in my table :/

Comment: Thank you @Gary_W, I really appreciate it!