# SQL how to take a comma delimited list (sting format) and sort it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table as shown below. The column "newDataIDs" is a comma delimited list but the column itself is in varchar format. How can I sort the values in column in ascending order and put it back to the column in varchar format?

(i.e for 2nd row of the table the expected value for newDataIDs is:
"WVR0000015, WVR0000019, WVR0000020")

[image]

Edit:
Thanks to @METAL,I have gotten the anwer. I have incorporated his answer into my case as follow:

```
 update [db].[dbo].[mytable] set [NewDataIDs] = t.ids
 from  (
 SELECT STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) sorted
            FROM
            (
                SELECT CAST('<t>'+REPLACE([NewDataIDs], ',', '</t><t>')+'</t>' AS XML) AS String
            ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/t') AS Split(a)
            ORDER BY sorted asc
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') as ids
        from [db].[dbo].[mytable]
 ) t
```

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are using with version ?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: I think you would need to write a stored procedure to handle this.

Comment: You could do this in a stored procedure (I would probably place the parsed items in the list in a temporary table). However, SQL is not ideal for string manipulation. It's probably better to do this in the client app.

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769913/sql-server-sort-comma-separated-string-in-one-column]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your script.

```
declare @str varchar(max)

set @str = 'WVR0000015, WVR0000019, WVR0000020'

SELECT STUFF((
          SELECT ',' +ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) sorted
            FROM
            (
                SELECT CAST('<t>'+REPLACE(@str, ',', '</t><t>')+'</t>' AS XML) AS String
            ) AS A
            CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/t') AS Split(a)
            ORDER BY sorted asc
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```